# Exception Error Pass Issues

Tags: python, twitter, error-handling, syntax-error

I am trying to make the program check the csv file every 3 seconds for a line to tweet, and if it finds duplicates, it terminates, so i am trying to figure out how to pass the duplicate error correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import tweepy, time, sys

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

CONSUMER_KEY = 'example'
CONSUMER_SECRET =  'example'
ACCESS_KEY =  'example'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'example'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

for line in f:
try:
    api.update_status(line)
except tweepy.error.TweepError:
    pass
    time.sleep(3)#Tweet every 3 seconds
```

idk if its because of the indentation on the error section, but it will not pass the error. i get invalid syntax and indentation error for the except and pass lines, can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This line has an extra single quote before the string:

```
ACCESS_SECRET = ' 'example'
```

Remove one of them before the "example".